# Casting an int to a short gives unexpected results

Tags: c#, casting

I'm a little confused about loss information on numeric types in C#.

When i do this:

```
int x = 32780;
short y = (short)x;
```

I have the result: -32756 for y and not the expected 32767. Why? How this is calculated?

Range of short: -32768 to 32767 
Range of int: -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Comment: Why do you expect 32767?

Comment: try `y = checked((short)x)` - what happens?

Answer (score 53):

You seem to be expecting a “rounding down” effect rather than what is actually happening, which is a bitwise re-interpretation of the data.

In binary, `x` is equal to `00000000000000001000000000001100`, which is a 32-bit number with only 16 significant bits. A `short` is a 16-bit *signed* integer which is represented using [two’s complement notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

When you convert, the last 16 bits of your `x` are being copied into `y`, giving `1000000000001100`.  Importantly here, the first digit is a `1`. In two’s-complement notation, this is `-32756`. Your number hasn't been rounded—it’s been read as though it were 16-bit.

Answer (score 14):

Read Dan's answer for the "true" reason this happens, but it'll suffice to think about it like this: When a number overflows its maximum, it loops back around to the minimum. So, `32780 - 32767 = 13` and `-32768 (which is one of the 13) + 12 (the other 12) = -32756`

Comment: It's more to do with bit patterns but nevertheless a helpful answer

Comment: True, but that's not quite why this is happening.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan yeah, I was gonna take the logical route and not go into the binary behind it. Good point though, it should at least be noted

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: Surely the whole point of the way binary numbers are usually represented is that the above mathemtical logic is always correct? You could argue equally that the bit pattern is just a representation of the above logic. And for most people the overflow logic is easier to understand I would suspect.

Comment: @Chris yeah, that was the concept I was going for

Comment: The thing is, your theory doesn't quite hold true because of the inaccuracy - it only holds for a number that is exactly 16-bits long.  If I take `int x = 163841` (binary `101000000000000001`) and convert to a short, the result is `-32767`: it's just truncated, not overflowed.

Comment: @Chris: the overflow logic is easier to understand for simple examples, but soon falls apart for something more complex, and will just cause greater confiusion.  The example in the original question *only* behaves in this way because the original 32-bit value has exactly 16 significant digits.

Comment: @Dan: No, it works for anything... If you are counting up to 163841 then you get to 32767 then you count another 65536 and you are back to 32767 (having wrapped around and counted through all the negative numbers). You count another 65536 and you are back to 32767 (and have counted a total of 163839). You then count another one to -32768 and then another one to -32767. Total counted is 163841 and final result is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: @Chris: Actually yes, fair point: any significant digit added will be a multiple of 32768, so the overflow will always cancel out.  And for negative numbers you count upwards by groups of 65536 until you're in range.  I still contend that it's worth understanding properly, though ;-)

Comment: @DanPuzey: Oh yes, definitely. But its also worth understanding that the reason we use two's complement binary representations is because addition and subtraction work so nicely as this answer suggests. Its why computers can add up numbers like this so easily (much nicer than one's complement).

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I submitted an alternative answer to this question, focusing on the math behind that.

Comment: Chris has it. The whole point of twos-complement rather than ones complement is that whether you think of it as wrapping around, or as truncating, you get the same answer.

Answer (score 6):

One could say that the runtime adds or subtracts `65536` as many times as is needed to get a number within the range of the `short` (`System.Int16`) type.

If you know a lot of pure math, instead of explaining it through the internal binary representation (which is also cool), you can understand it from [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

For this, consider the type `short` to be the integers modulo 65536, also written as ℤ/65536ℤ. Each member of ℤ/65536ℤ is a *congruence class*, i.e. a set of numbers all having the same remainder when divided by 65536. Now, each congruence class has an infinitude of different members ("representatives"). If you pick one, you get all the others by repeatingly adding or subtracting 65536.

With the `short` data type, we pick the unique representative in the interval `-32768` through `+32767`. Then the `ushort` is the same thing, only do we pick the representative in `0` through `65535`.

Now the cool thing about ℤ/65536ℤ is that it forms a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) in which we have **addition**, **subtraction** and **multiplication** (but **not** division). And actually, in `unchecked` context, with `short x,y;`, the C# operations

```
(short)(x + y)
(short)(x - y)
(short)(x * y)
```

correspond exactly to the arithmetic in ℤ/65536ℤ. (We have to cast back to `short` here because technically C# defines the operators only for `int`, `uint`, `long`, and `ulong`.)

In the same way, `sbyte` and `byte` can be thought of as the ring ℤ/256ℤ, `int` and `uint` as ℤ/4294967296ℤ, and `long` and `ulong` as ℤ/18446744073709551615ℤ.

Note, however, that because these moduli are not primes, division is not possible in the ring. For example, no `int X` satisfies

```
unchecked( 10 * X == 35 )   // integers Int32
```

and therefore it's not clear what `35/10` should be. On the other hand, **two** `X` satisfy

```
unchecked( 10 * X == 36 )   // integers Int32
```

but which of them should be `36/10`?

However, exactly one `int X` makes

```
unchecked( 11 * X == 35 )   // integers Int32
```

true. We're having luck because 11 is relatively prime to 4294967296. The solution `X` is 1952257865 (check for yourself), so the quotient `35/11` is in a sense that number `X`.

Conclusion: The integer operations `+`, `-`, and `*` of C# can be interpreted as simply the ring operations in ℤ/nℤ. But the `/` operation is in no way related to the ring!

Answer (score 3):

When you cast x to short you will get an overflow (i.e. the value being assigned more than it could handle) and your value would be represented as thought it would start over again starting from the min value. As you said, short's max value is 32767 so your new value would be: -32768 + (32780 - 32768) = -32756

Depending on the programming language (and perhaps your compiler), what you're trying to do could bring an exception or not. It seems in C# it doesn't.

Comment: In C#, integer overflows don't throw unless you are in a `checked` block

Answer (score 2):

There is an overflow. If you want the number to be capped to the maximum value, you can work around this by comparing the integer to `short.MaxValue`:

```
short y;
if (x > short.MaxValue) {
    y = short.MaxValue;
} else if (x < short.MinValue) {
    y = short.MinValue;
} else {
    y = (short)x;
}
```

Comment: You should also check for `x < short.MinValue`, for completeness.